# Java3D 3D CAD file import and display

Tags: java, autocad, java-3d, cad

My client has a 3D AutoCad DWG file of a structure that I'd like to import, display in Java3D and interact with as part of a larger program.

So I'm wondering what to convert the DWG to for easy import and whether Java code exists to display it.

I've got experience using Java3D to render models of the seabed but am not an expert. Currently my software imports 2D WMF files but the client wants 3D.

Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: Did you consider using a cloud service like [EWS](http://www.devdept.com/eyeshot/webservice)? You can convert DWG in a easy to parse XML file format.

Answer (score 1):

The Forge [Viewer](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2) can be embedded on a browser control on your app. It works for 2D and 3D.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. I used ABViewer to convert the DWG file to an STL file. Then I used the org.j3d STLFileLoader to load it into my code. This post set me on the right track:

http://forum.jogamp.org/STLLoader-td4032481.html

STLFileLoader seems efficient, it loads a 22Mb model in under a second on my fairly slow PC.

Comment: STLFileLoader isn't bad, let us know whether you need a more efficient STL importer.